# Can I make Qemu exit with failure on kernel panic?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu, init-script, kernel-panic

I'm trying to add Qemu to my continuous integration pipeline to test various `initrd` artifacts. I've already discovered that I can run Qemu like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -machine q35 \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=OVMF_CODE.fd,readonly \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=OVMF_VARS.fd \
    -kernel vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic \
    -initrd my-initramfs.cpio.xz \
    -nographic
```

...and cause `qemu-system-x86_64` to exit with status `0` if I do this in my `init` script:

```
# poweroff -f
```

This is works because the init script doesn't exit -- it invokes `poweroff -f` and sleeps "forever" or until Qemu does a "Power Down":

```
ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
reboot: Power down
```

I would like to be able to detect problems in the `init` script by forcing an `exit` on error via `set -eu`. Exiting the `init` script (correctly) causes a kernel panic but the `qemu-system-x86_64` process hangs forever.

How can I keep it from hanging forever? How do I get the Qemu host to detect a kernel panic in the Qemu guest?

Further clarification:

The nature of my application is security-sensitive; i.e., configuring/compiling the linux kernel is "allowed", but passing kernel parameters is not. To put a fine point on it, [`CMDLINE_OVERRIDE`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE_OVERRIDE.html) is enabled.

Comment: @dsstorefile1, this one? https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PVPANIC.html

Comment: @dsstorefile1, or this one?

    $ qemu-system-x86_64 -device help 2>&1 | grep -i panic
    name "pvpanic", bus ISA

Comment: @meuh ah, I had that [on my cheatsheet but had forgotten](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/faec16e00c4dca07eb57f5fdc02b999bc07a0ac5#shutdown-vm-on-panic)! I can confirm it works on x86_64, arm and aarch64 -M virt (exits 0 however like `pvpanic`) Is there any advantage of pvpanic over that method? Will you write an answer or shall I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got something that's working:

- Configure (and build) the kernel with `CONFIG_PVPANIC=y`; this produces a kernel with compiled-in support for the `pvpanic` device.
- Invoke `qemu-system-x86_64` with the `-device pvpanic` option; this instructs Qemu to catch (and exit on) a kernel panic.

A kernel panic causes `qemu-system-x86_64` to exit successfully (return status `0`), but at least it's not hanging anymore.

Many thanks to @dsstorefile1 for pointing me in the right direction.

References:

- https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PVPANIC.html
- https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/specs/pvpanic.txt

Answer (score 13):

**QEMU `-no-reboot` + kernel CLI `panic=-1`**

- `qemu-system-X -no-reboot` QEMU CLI option: makes QEMU exit when the guest tries to reboot
- `panic=-1` kernel boot parameter: makes Linux try to reboot immediately after a panic: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L2931

It also returns `0` like `pvpanic`, but has the following advantages:

- no need to recompile anything, just a boot parameter
- works on arm and aarch64 `-M virt` as well as x86, while pvpanic seems x86-specific since it is under `arch/x86`

Tested with [this setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/13e0ea78015401c538de2515ac4ffc555a8cd78c#exit-emulator-on-panic).

**Track the `panic` symbol with GDB**

Another way to go about this might be to detect when the address of the `panic` function is reached, and then try to make QEMU quit.

You can definitely break GDB on `panic` as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642

But then TODO: how to make QEMU exit with status 1? Using `monitor quit`, from inside GDB, which forwards `quit` to the QEMU monitor from GDB, gets really close, but not quite since it does not exit with status `0`.

[gem5](http://www.gem5.org/) does this tracking by default natively, which is pretty awesome.

This happens at: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/1da285dfcc31b904afc27e440544d006aae25b38/src/arch/arm/linux/system.cc#L73

Maybe QEMU devs can take some inspiration from this technique and implement something similar.

Comment: this is a great answer and I've upvoted you accordingly. The only reason I'm not denoting yours as THE answer is because of the security-sensitive caveats that were not part of my original question. I've updated the question to that effect; I do apologize for omitting that detail initially.